# Use optional variable in dashboard

Tags: influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

I using influxdb to create a dashboard and i have a variable define by

```
import "influxdata/influxdb/schema"

schema.tagValues(bucket: v.bucket, tag: "my-tag")
```

I can use the variable in my dashboard with this example query.

```
from(bucket: v.bucket)
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "aMeasure")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["my-tag"] == v.myTag)
    |> cumulativeSum()
    

  |> yield()
```

But i want to have the possibility to not select a value and have an unfiltered dashboard but i don't find how to do that with influxdb dashboard and query

Answer (score 1):

I wish I knew a better way, but I did this.

1. variable value is a union of existing tag values and special values (`'<all>'` in this case):

```js
import "csv"
import "influxdata/influxdb/v1"

actual = v1.tagValues(
  bucket: myBucket,
  tag: "name",
  predicate: (r) => true,
)

csvData = "
#datatype,string,long,string
#group,false,false,false
#default,,,
,result,table,_value
,,0,<all>
"

special = csv.from(csv: csvData)
union(tables: [special, actual])
```

2. query has `if` condition in `filter` handling the wildcard value

```js
  ...
  |> filter(fn: (r) => if v.name == "<all>" then true else r.name == v.name)
  ...
```